# Steps for deployment of Container Instance with Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances, azure-rest-api

I'd like to automate the deployment of a virtual network (that is peered with another network) and container instance connected to that network.
I'd just want to confirm that I'd do the correct steps. I'll be using Azure REST API.

1. Deploy a Virtual Network with a subnet
2. Create a Peering to the other virtual network
3. Create a Network Profile
4. Deploy the Container with the created network profile.

Step 3 is a bit weird for me because it's different than what I do in the Azure Portal. In the Portal, I just select the virtual network that I want my container to be connected to. Looking at MSDN Docs it seems to me that REST API requires me to create that Network Profile first. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy an container using `az container create` the az cli will create the network profile for you in the background.

This might be why you might not have seen explicit creation of the network profile before.

```
A network profile is a network configuration template for Azure resources. It specifies certain network properties for the resource, for example, the subnet into which it should be deployed. When you first use the az container create command to deploy a container group to a subnet (and thus a virtual network), Azure creates a network profile for you. You can then use that network profile for future deployments to the subnet.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#network-profile

You steps are looking good.